# Why does a div containing an img tag of the same height have a vertical scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have an absolutely-positioned `<div>` with a set height and width. It contains an `<img>` tag with the exact same height and width. I've removed all padding, margins and borders in sight. I'd expect the `<img>` to fit snugly inside the `<div>`, but instead I get a vertical scrollbar which lets me go up and down about 4px.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="maybe-scroll">
  <img src="..." width="100" height="100" border="0" padding="0" margin="0">
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
img, #maybe-scroll {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}
#maybe-scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/yimixu/3/edit?html,output

The 4px discrepancy shows up in Chrome's dev tools:

```
> $('#maybe-scroll').clientHeight
100
> $('#maybe-scroll').scrollHeight
104
```

Firefox reports 100 for both values but still shows the vertical scrollbar.

What is causing this vertical scrolling and how can I eliminate it? I'd prefer not to just set `overflow: hidden`, since in my real application it's possible that other elements in the same view will be tall enough to warrant scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`img` elements are inline elements. By default, inline elements have a `vertical-align` of `baseline`. Even though there's no text there, the bottom of the image is still being aligned with where the baseline of any letters would be. Some space is required below the baseline to allow for letters with descenders (j, y, etc). That space for descenders is what's taking up the extra 4 pixels. If you add some text inside the div, and widen the div to allow room for both the letters and the image, this becomes pretty clear.

There are a couple ways to fix it. You can set `vertical-align: bottom` on the image. This will align the bottom of the image with the bottom of where any letter descenders would be. Or, you could set the image to `display: block`, so you don't need to worry about the vertical alignment. The latter will be fine as long as the image is the only thing inside the div, but might cause other problems if you have other elements inside the div.